# PHP conditionally pass nested arrays as function argument

Tags: php, arrays, function, conditional-statements, parameter-passing

I got two nested index arrays, which I want to populate with values using a function.

But on a conditional basis: if this, populate the first array; if that, populate the second array.

Here is what I got:

WORKING, but repetitive

```
$sectionCounter = 0;

foreach($sections as $section) {
    if ($direction === 'up') {
        $array1[$sectionCounter][] = 1; 
        $array1[$sectionCounter][] = 25;
        // ...
    }   else {
        $array2[$sectionCounter][] = 1; 
        $array2[$sectionCounter][] = 25;
        // ...
    }
    $sectionCounter++;
}
```

PREFERRED (not working yet)

```
function addElements($temp, $sectionCounter) {
        $temp[$sectionCounter][] = 1; 
        $temp[$sectionCounter][] = 25;
        // ...
}

foreach($sections as $section) {
    if ($direction === 'up') {
        addElements($array1, $sectionCounter);
    } else { 
        addElements($array2, $sectionCounter);
    }
    $sectionCounter++;
}
```

Comment: And what is the question? Sidenote: your `addElements` function __returns nothing__.

Comment: To actually add something to the resulting array, you either need to return the new value: `return $temp;` at the end of the function and then store the response: `$array1 = addElements($array1, ....);`. Or you can simply [pass the array by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Then all you need to do is add a `&` in front of the argument: `function addElements(&$temp, $sectionCounter)`.

Comment: I am unsure if `$array1` and `$array2` are previously declared.  This matters if you are declaring the subarrays for the first time or if you are potentially overwriting data.  Can you please provide a [mcve]?  By showing a minimal sample of data and expressing your exact desired output, we can confidently give you great guidance. @george

Comment: @george Does this do everything you need? https://3v4l.org/C0S58

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach instead

```
$sectionCounter = 0;
$data = [
   'up' => $array1,
   'other' => $array2
];
foreach($sections as $section) {
    $dir = $direction === 'up'? 'up': 'other';
    
    $data[$dir][$sectionCounter][] = 1; 
    $data[$dir][$sectionCounter][] = 25;
        // ...
   
    $sectionCounter++;
}

$array1 = $data['up'];
$array2 = $data['other'];
```